# Showing that a function is totally differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the function $f(x,y)=|x+\pi|^3e^{3y}$ is totally differentiable. I already calculated the gradient, $\textrm{grad}\ f=(3|x+\pi|^2e^{3y},\ 3|x+\pi|^3e^{3y})$.

I know I need to show that for an $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^2$ it holds that \begin{equation}\lim_{x\rightarrow\xi}\frac{||f(x)-f(\xi)-A(x-\xi)||}{||x-\xi||}=0,\end{equation} where the unique lineair image $A: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the total derivative.

I don't know how I can show anything with this...

Comment: Your gradient is wrong, your gradient is the gradient of the function $(x+\pi)^3 e^{3y}$. One way to see its not right is that the function for fixed $y$ is decreasing in $x$, if $x\ll -1$ is sufficiently negative. Yet your partial in $x$ is always positive

Comment: @Calvin: the notation $a\ll b$ is almost exclusively used to mean $|a|\leq C|b|$ for some absolute constant $C$. Do you have a reference for how you’re using the notation?

Comment: @Clayton hmm, no reference, I was just using it in a way that felt natural. I didn't want to write $|x| \gg 1$ and $x<0$ is all. I am interested to see if anyone has used this notation in this way...

In cases like $|x| \ll \epsilon $ i'm always careful to make sure that I'm only comparing positive quantities, so really in my mind it was defined as $ a\ll b \iff a \le C b$ for some universal constant $C$. Your definition seems to suggest that I can start writing $x\ll \epsilon$, at least for $x\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Clayton I've asked a separate question about this here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985907/use-of-the-notation-a-ll-b-for-a-b-maybe-not-positive

Comment: @Calvin: if $\varepsilon$ is fixed, then $|x|\ll\varepsilon$ just means that $x$ is no bigger than some absolute constant (this is equivalent to $x\ll1$). I use (and read in the literature) things like $f(t)\ll 1/\log t$ to indicate that, at worst, $f(t)$ decays like $1/\log t$ (it could be much faster in reality, but maybe out of reach for proof).

Comment: @Clayton sorry, I didn't mean to imply that $\epsilon$ was fixed. Playing with the notation, I find $ x\gg 1$ and $x<0$ to be painful to write. Perhaps also we shouldn't derail the comments of this question.